# Вопрос по требованию к оформлению кода при работе с Unity. public или [SerializeField]private

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я столкнулся с дилеммой по поводу оформления. У меня есть скрипт который отвечает за обновление GUI инвентаря игрока, соответственно, есть и поля в которые передаётся текст, который мы, непосредственно, и будем обновлять. Стоит ли сделать это поле `[SerializeField]private`, так как нигде оно больше не используется, кроме как в этом скрипте, или оставить `public`, что, как мне кажется, смотрится лаконично (такой себе аргумент).
   Буду рад ссылке которая более подробнее расскажет об оформлении кода.
   *Заранее спасибо за ответы, не судите строго, от части данный вопрос был задан что бы получше познакомится с площадкой stackoverflow.*[image: мой код]

Comment: Оставить поле `public` ради лаконичности - гениально!

Comment: А при чем тут "оформление кода", как модификатор доступа относится к этому? Они относятся к инкапсуляции, но не к "оформлению". Вот вы заходите в магазин, вам надо купить бутыль воды. У магазина все открыто (склад, все помещения), вы вольны делать что угодно, но по правилам. И вот полезли на склад за бутылкой воды, попутно перепутали там часть товара, потом пошли на кассу, пока понимали как пробить все это, вы например сломали кассовый аппарат. Почему так произошло? Да потому, что у вас был доступ к тому, что не для вас. Так и в программе - класс должен выдавать наружу только то, что надо.

Comment: Теперь `[SerializeField]` - вы понимаете для чего этот атрибут? У вас это происходит с данным классом? По вашему описанию (`за обновление GUI инвентаря игрока`) лично я не вижу необходимости в сериализации данного класса, тогда вопрос - зачем?

Comment: Может я не правильно выразился. Мой вопрос в том как лучше оформить код. Что я хочу: я хочу сокрыть полу, что бы не нарушать инкапсуляции, но мне необходима иметь доступ к данному полю в инспекторе, а единственный известный мне способ получить доступ к приватному полю в инспекторе это добавить ему атрибут [SerializeFild]. Я, вроде как, понимаю что такое сериализацию и полностью согласен, что она мне тут абсолютно не нужна. Только вопрос остаётся открытым. Как лучше поступить?

Comment: Эм, "доступ к переменной в инспекторе" - это часть всего страшного процесса в юнити, что зовется "сериализация". Инспектор позволяет изменять сериализуемые данные. Если вам просто нужно посмотреть, что у вас там написано в переменной - используйте Debug режим инспектора или напишите свой инспектор для своего класса.

Comment: Возможно на ваш вопрос отвечают конвенции. Есть конвенция от майкрософта [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже написал EvgeniyZ в комментариях к вопросу

> Модификаторы доступа относятся к инкапсуляции, но не к "оформлению".

Понять как лучше оформлять код помогут конвенции, например от Microsoft [по C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) и [общие рекомендации по именованию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Что касается [SerializeField], то этот атрибут указывает Unity что отмеченное поле класса нужно сериализовать, даже если оно приватное. (Более подробно про SerializeField и другие атрибуты используемые в Unity можно почитать в официальной [документации Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html))

[Unity использует сериализацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/script-Serialization.html), в часности, для удобной работы в редакторе - сохранение и настройка префабов через изменение полей классов. Сюда относится и инъекция зависимостей(прокидывание ссылок, проще говоря. Именно это и подразумевается в коде в Вашем вопросе).

**И теперь ответ на вопрос**

> У меня есть скрипт который отвечает за обновление GUI инвентаря игрока, соответственно, есть и поля в которые передаётся текст, который мы, непосредственно, и будем обновлять.

В данном случае, поля `FoodCount` и `TrophyCount` должны быть инкапсулированы в классе `BagUI`. Соответственно нужно установить им модификатор доступа `private`.
Теперь, чтобы иметь возможность задать полям значения, добавляем атрибут `SerializeField` и прокидываем ссылки на нужные компоненты текста Unity через редактор. Таким образом, инкапсуляция не нарушена, а нужные значения полей установлены. Всё, вы прекрасны.

---

Стоит отметить, что есть ещё, как минимум, один способ задать значения приватных *не сериализуемых* полей, которым очень часто пользуются. С помошью `MonoBehaviour.GetComponent` и подобных ему. Например в методе Start или Awake.

При таком подходе, если мы пытаемся взять компонент у GameObject на котором исполняется текущий код, следует добавить к классу с исполняемым кодом атрибут [RequireComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html), и это будет гарантировать, что при попытке получить нужный компонент - мы его получим (на самом деле не будет, но это уже совсем другая история).

Например, это может выглядеть так

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]
public class BagUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text _foodCount;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _foodCount = this.GetComponent<Text>();
    }    
}
```

Однако, если нужно получить компоненты из других GameObject, то мы не можем гарантировать их наличие во время выполнения приложения. И самым надёжным и правильным способом инъекций зависимостей является использование атрибута `SerializeField` и ручное прокидывание ссылок через редактор. (`SerializeField` явно покажет Вам в редакторе, что у скрипта есть зависимость и её нужно назначить).